# using regex to match a string including with numbers and special characters

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to use regex to match a string with it. The string is like this. It starts by the word "Figure" then a white space, then any random number, then `:`,then white space and then a random stream of characters. The regex I made is as below:

```
                   String pattern="Figure\\s\\d:\\s\\w+";
```

But it is not working and returns false for a string like:

```
Figure 1: Prototype architecture
```

Comment: The regex seems about right (note that it will catch only the first word after the `:`). Could you add the code using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Figure\s*\d\s*\:.*
```

Your example does not have a space after the number so either drop the `\s` after the `\d` or make it optional with `\s*`. Also you are wanting to match anything after the colin so use `.*` to say anything after this.

Use https://regex101.com/ to play and learn.

Comment: I edited my question. i made a mistake to mention the space after the : and not before number. and thanks, that is working. so this will match for any length of strings?

Comment: and another question, I tried to add a char class like `[:.]` to match either `Figure 1:` and `Figure 1.`. but there was no results which i supposed i did something wrong?  `Figure\\s*\\d\\s*\\[:.].*`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a \s\w+ at the end. Try:

```
"Figure\\s\\d:\\s\\w+\\s\\w+"
```

You regex only matched up to:

```
Figure 1: Prototype
```

Comment: this looks working. but why added `\\s\\w+`? i can not get it.

Comment: You matched only up until the end of the word "Prototype" and not until the end of "architecture"

Comment: oh i see. there is another question, what if there is more words with white space? i mean i want it to match with any arbitrary number of words, separated with white spaces.

Comment: [\w\s]* this should work or if you want only letters and spaces [a-zA-Z ]* should work.

Answer (score 0):

Figure 1: Prototype architecture is true with:

```
 ^Figure[ ]\d:[ ].+$
```

Be carefull, if you forget comming with ^ this string "somethingFigure 1: Prototype architecture" will be return true.

And i think is good idea use $ for the end of the regexp. But in this case is not necesary.